# ios how to extract the id number part from an app store url?

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to extract the id number part from an app store url, for example, following are two app store urls:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id882456583?pt=63826800&ct=%E5%AE%A3%E4%BC%A0%E8%B4%B4001&mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/app/juan-pi-zhe-kou-shou-ji-shang/id639388447?mt=8&uo=4

I would like to extract the number after "id", i.e. 882456583 and 639388447.
Anyone knows how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Swift :

```
let appStoreUrl = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/juan-pi-zhe-kou-shou-ji-shang/id639388447?mt=8&uo=")
let appId = appStoreUrl?.lastPathComponent?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("id", withString: "")
```

Objective C :

```
NSURL *appStoreUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/juan-pi-zhe-kou-shou-ji-shang/id639388447?mt=8&uo="];
NSString *appId = [appStoreUrl.lastPathComponent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"id" withString:@""];
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you are expecting is this

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id882456583?pt=63826800&ct=%E5%AE%A3%E4%BC%A0%E8%B4%B4001&mt=8"] resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
NSLog(@"id = %@",[[[components valueForKey:@"path"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject]);
```

in logs you ll have required param.

Comment: This gives something like:"<NSURLQueryItem 0x14e27290> {name = mt, value = 8}",  I need the app id, not these parameters

Comment: you want only this `id639388447` right ? or 63826800 ?